# Is it possible to set fix under replica to be done automatically when needed from ambari?

Tags: hdfs, ambari, hdp

We have `ambari` cluster - HDP version `2.6.5`

from time to time we see under replica in ambari dashboard , ( it means that under replica need to fix )

When I saw this, I ran the `HDFS` command that fixes it.

but I want to know if we can set some parameters that will do it automatically , by changing some values from `ambari` configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Anirban166 Yes, you can certainly do this.  I would warn against automating this task and silently forgetting about it.   They left it like this on purpose so that Administrators may evaluate why there is data loss and take some corrective action if one is required before running the HDFS command and/or rebalancing.